# Selenium Hub doesn't connect to application server

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, kubernetes, selenium-chromedriver, minikube

We have deployed our selenium automation test case on kubernetes. We have Selenium hub and selenium node debug running for version 3.141.59.

We have initialized the RemoteWebDriver with URL "http://selenium-hub:4444/wd/hub".
While running the automation test cases we observed that it is not connecting to the actual application server that we want to hit from the automation test cases but I am getting 200 response code.
As it is not hitting the actual application server while accessing application attribute we are getting "NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element".

Has anybody encountered such issue and how they have resolved it?

Comment: How did you conclude _...not connecting to the actual application server..._

Comment: I was monitoring the actual application server logs and I dont see any request coming there.